# For loops inside of a variable

Tags: python

I've been trying to use a for loop inside of a variable, but it gives me the error: Expected expression to the right of "="

Here's my code:

```
import random

password=
        for i in range(4):
            i=chr(random.randint(65,90))
            for x in range(6):
                x=chr(random.randint(65,90)).lower()
                for j in range(10):
                    j=str(random.randint(1,9))
                password=str(password)+i+x+j
```

I've tried moving the first line next to the "=" but that won't work. I also tried to mess with the indents and swapping the = with a colon, but those didn't work either.

I'm just starting out with python and trying to put a for loop in a variable, really shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: What do you want to achieve "putting for loop in a variable"? It doesn't make any sense. Variable is something that stores the information, for loop isn't one. Do you want to create a function?

Comment: Putting a for loop "in a variable" does not make any sense in Python. It sounds like you either trying to store a statement in a variable (not possible), or you're trying to use a statement as an expression (for loops, if statements, etc aren't expression; they don't resolve to a value). Looking at the rest of you code, it seems like you have several misconceptions about how Python works. You'll probably get better help by asking about the specific problem you're trying to solve rather than your guess at how to solve it. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: What do you think the value of a `for` loop would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a loop and just resetting the random variable each time you run the loop and in turn just continuously changing the password for no apparent gain.

If you just want a password of those parameters, drop the for loops altogether:

```
from random import randint

password = ''
n = 10

for _ in range(n):
    password = password + chr(randint(65, 90)) + chr(randint(65, 90)) + str(randint(1, 9))
```

(edit, confused on your goal at first)

Comment: Consider `+=` for terser concatenation. Also, this might be a place where `''.join(...sequence...)` makes more sense from a performance perspective (don't need to make things [accidentally quadratic](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/)).